# Why my methods for React function components don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themoviedb-api

I am developing a project with Moviedb api. I created the movie list under the name Movie component. I make my api requests in this component. From the Movie component to the MovieInfo component, I send the release date of the movie and the genres of the movie via props.

But I cannot apply substring and map methods to these properties that come to me in the MovieInfo component with props.

```
class Movie extends Component {

state = {
    movie: [],
    loading: false,
    actors: [],
    directors: [],
    visible : 6 // This state is for how many actors rendered. 
}



componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    })

    let moviesEndPoint = `${BASE_URL}/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=tr`
    let creditsEndPoint = `${BASE_URL}/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}/credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
    this.getMovieWithId(moviesEndPoint);
    this.getDirectorsAndActors(creditsEndPoint);
}

getMovieWithId = moviesEndPoint => {
    fetch(moviesEndPoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((movie) => {
            // console.log(movie);

            if (movie.overview !== "" && !movie.status_code) {
                this.setState({
                    movie,
                    loading: false
                })
            }
            else { // if have not turkish overview fetch this 
                let engEndPoint = `${BASE_URL}/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}`
                fetch(engEndPoint)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((movie) => {
                        this.setState({
                            movie
                        })
                    })
            }
        })
}

getDirectorsAndActors = creditsEndPoint => {
    fetch(creditsEndPoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((credits) => {
            // console.log(credits)
            const filterDirector = credits.crew.filter(person => person.job === "Director"); // filter directors from all employees
            // console.log(filterDirector)
            this.setState({
                actors: credits.cast,
                directors: filterDirector[0].name,
                loading: false
            })
        })
}

render() {
        const { movie, loading, actors, directors, visible } = this.state
        const { location } = this.props
    return (
        <>
            {
                loading ? <Spinner /> : null
            }
            {this.state.movie ?
                <MovieInfo
                    movieInfo={movie}
                    actors={actors}
                    directors={directors}
                    searchWord={location.searchWord}
                    visible = {visible}
                    loadMore = {this.loadMore}
                    loading = {loading}
                /> : null
            }

            {
                !actors && !loading ? <h1>Film Bulunamadı! </h1> : null
            }

        </>
    )
}
```

}

This is the non-working code inside my MovieInfo component and my errors like this :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined



const MovieInfo = ({ movieInfo, searchWord, directors, actors, visible, loadMore, loading }) => {

const editReleaseDate = (date) => {  //? Idk why doesn't work !
    // return date.substring(5).split("-").concat(date.substring(0,4)).join("/")
    return date

    // console.log(date)
    // return date;
}

return (

<Col sm={5} className="movieInfo p-4 animated fadeInRightBig">
                <p className = "movie-title" > {movieInfo.title} </p>
                <h5 className = "mb-4 text-warning">Yayınlanma Tarihi: <span className = "text-light">{editReleaseDate(movieInfo.release_date)}</span></h5>
                <h5 className = "text-warning">Açıklama</h5>
                <p>{movieInfo.overview} </p>
                <ProgressBar label={`IMDB: ${movieInfo.vote_average}`} animated now = {`${movieInfo.vote_average}`} min={0} max={10} />
                <h5 className = "text-warning mt-3">Türü: 

                {  //? Idk why doesn't work !
                    // movieInfo.genres.map((genre, i) => {
                    //     return <span key = {i} >{genre.name}</span>
                    // })
                }

                </h5>
                <h5 className ="mt-2 text-warning">Yönetmen:  <span className = "text-light">{directors} </span> </h5>
                <div> <i className="fas fa-film fa-5x"></i> </div>
            </Col>
)
```

Comment: If that's in a render, how are you handling the render before the data arrives?

Comment: I edited my code .  Its a  functional component. Can't I do editing within the functional component?

Comment: How are you handling rendering before the async data is delivered? (Note this question is very similar to the first one I asked--it's quicker to just answer the first time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 `loading` state for 2 api calls so once one is finishing it is telling the component that it is done loading even if the second has finished. I split it up into 2 different loading states, `loadingMovie` & `loadingActors`.

```
class Movie extends Component {

 state = {
    movie: [],
    loadingMovie: false,
    loadingActors: false,
    actors: [],
    directors: [],
    visible : 6 // This state is for how many actors rendered. 
 };

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        loadingMovie: true,
        loadingActors: true,
    });

    let moviesEndPoint = `${BASE_URL}/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=tr`;
    let creditsEndPoint = `${BASE_URL}/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}/credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
    this.getMovieWithId(moviesEndPoint);
    this.getDirectorsAndActors(creditsEndPoint);
}

getMovieWithId = moviesEndPoint => {
    fetch(moviesEndPoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((movie) => {
            // console.log(movie);

            if (movie.overview !== "" && !movie.status_code) {
                this.setState({
                    movie,
                    loadingMovie: false
                })
            }
            else { // if have not turkish overview fetch this 
                let engEndPoint = `${BASE_URL}/movie/${this.props.match.params.movieId}?api_key=${API_KEY}`
                fetch(engEndPoint)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then((movie) => {
                        this.setState({
                            movie,
                            loadingMovie: false
                        });
                    })
            }
        })
}

getDirectorsAndActors = creditsEndPoint => {
    fetch(creditsEndPoint)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((credits) => {
            // console.log(credits)
            if (credits && credits.crew) {
               const filterDirector = credits.crew.filter(person => person.job === "Director"); // filter directors from all employees
               // console.log(filterDirector)
               this.setState({
                   actors: credits.cast,
                   directors: filterDirector[0].name,
                   loadingActors: false
               })
            } else {
               console.log('bad credits');
            }
        })
}

render() {
        const { movie, loadingActors, loadingMovie, actors, directors, visible } = this.state;
        const { location } = this.props;
    return (
        <>
            {loadingActors || loadingMovie ? <Spinner /> :
            (movie.length && actors.length) ?
                <MovieInfo
                    movieInfo={movie}
                    actors={actors}
                    directors={directors}
                    searchWord={location.searchWord}
                    visible = {visible}
                    loadMore = {this.loadMore}
                    loading = {(loadingActors || loadingMovie)}
                /> : null
            }
            {
                actors.length && !loadingActors ? <h1>Film Bulunamadı! </h1> : null
            }
        </>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I am thankful to you MAN ! I Finally did it ! thank yo so much !!!

Comment: No problem!! :)